# How to get desired output from salt?

Tags: encryption, php, salt

If you wanted to get a specific output from php's $salt. function, how would you do this. By this I mean,

If you know $salt."*some_value*" gives you *desired_value*, how do you find that *some_value*, if you know what your *desired_value* is?

Comment: Which function are you talking about?

Comment: Are you looking for rainbow tables perhaps?

Comment: in PHP `.` is string concatenation  so `some_value` is a substring of `desired_value`